# Error while validating user in Android while connecting to magento

Tags: android, magento, xml-rpc

I am developing Android app that performs user login check.

My code is like follow,

```
XMLRPCClient client = new XMLRPCClient(url);
Object object = (String)client.call("login", EmailText,  PasswordText);
SessionId = object.toString();
```

where url is valid magento host path.
This code works only for admin account, means if I am login as admin user.
But it gives me error

> XMLRPC Fault: Access denied. [code 2]

for other users which enter email address and password.
I have also tried with using `customer.login` API but It gives

> Invalid api path error

.
What is wrong with this code?
Can anybody tell me correct method for user login?

Answer (score 1):

Magento does not provide such type of facility.I came to know magento uses md5 for hashing password.
I have written code for that.
Code is,

```
DemoMD5.MD5(salt+passwordText)+":"+salt;
```

salt is random string generated by magento,passwordText is password entered by user.